# Order of reaction greater than molecularity?

Tags: kinetics, elimination

We were taught that the order of a reaction is either less than or equal to it's molecularity. But then I came across a mechanism called E1CB, where the fact was totally reversed. Here molecularity is Unimolecular while the order of reaction is 2. 
So, is it any kind of exception or am I missing something?

Comment: This is because the E1CB reaction is a two step process. The elimination itself is unimolecular, but the concentrations of the intermediate depends on the concentration of the initial substrate and the base.